# 2 page methods on an aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I'm calling a page method with jquery and it works just fine. I'm creating a second one and it's not working at all; all I get is the error function. Is it possible to put more than 1 page method in an aspx page?

Here's my jquery on the client:

```
function LoadCount() {

    var TheObject = $.toJSON(CurrentForm);
    var TheParameter = "{'TheParameter' : '" + TheObject + "'}";

    $('#testobj').html("loading");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Pages/MyPage.aspx/GetCount",
        data: TheParameter,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFn,
        error: errorFn
    });

};

function successFn(thedata) {   $('#result').html(thedata.d); };
function errorFn() { alert("problem getting count"); };

function LoadData() {

    var ConfirmLoad = "test";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Pages/MyPage.aspx/GetLoaded",
        data: ConfirmLoad,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successLoad,
        error: errorLoad
    });

};

function successLoad(thedata) { alert((thedata.d)); };
function errorLoad() { alert("problem getting loaded"); };
```

And on the server side, I have this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetCount(string TheParameter)
{
  // some code
  return JsonResult;
}

[WebMethod]
public static string GetLoaded(string ConfirmLoad)
{
  return "test string";
}
```

LoadCount and GetCount work great, I thought I'd copy the implementation to create another page method but the second time, nothing good happens. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: It's possible to define more than one method in an aspx.cs|vb file, if that's what you're asking.  It would be helpful to include a couple code snippets of what you've done, what you expect to happen, and what's actually happening.

Comment: @Pete, just added code samples.

Comment: First, I need to find a way to work a function called GetLoaded() into my code today.  Second, the code samples are good but it's still very difficult to help you without more detail about exactly what happens in what order.  At the very least please include the detailed exception that you're receiving.      Have you tried setting breakpoints on your functions and seeing if they're getting called at all?

Comment: It was a problem with changing the datatypre from json to text.

Comment: Cool, glad SirViver got you sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `dataType: "text"` in the `$.ajax()` call properties if you're just returning plain text instead of a JSON encoded string.

You might also want to leave the `contentType` unspecified (at the default value of `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`) if your're *sending* plain text instead of a JS object.